# Ruby on Rails - How to Save Remote File over HTTPS and Basic Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, https, ruby-on-rails-2, open-uri

I am using a supplier's api and the response they send to our server includes a url to a file, upon trying to save this file locally I fail miserably.

```
def self.create_file_new(filename, ext, url)
  require 'open-uri'

  file = Tempfile.new(filename + ext) 
  file.binmode

  # data = open(url).read
  # data = open(url, :http_basic_authentication => [username, password])

  file << open(url, :http_basic_authentication => [username, password]).read
  # file.write CGI::unescape(data)

  file.close
  file = File.open(file.path)

  return file
end
```

I was originally getting a `OpenURI::HTTPError (401 Unauthorised):` but I have since created a file named `bypass_ssl_verification_for_open_uri in app/initializers` containing the following:

```
# Make open-uri work with https
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

which I found whilst Googling on how to fix it.

I then started to get this error message: `NoMethodError (undefined method 'tr' for #<StringIO:0xb5b728c4>):`, I tried creating another file (`cgi_escape_fix.rb` in `app/initializers`) containing this:

```
require 'cgi'
class << CGI
  alias_method :orig_escape, :escape
  def escape(str)
    orig_escape(str.to_str)
  end
end
```

Which I also found on my Google travels but that doesn't seem to have solved anything, so I commented out the `file.write CGI::unescape(data)` to try a different way but still no joy.

Now in the log I am just getting a plain `500 Internal Server Error` with no useful information.

The file I'm attempting to save will always be a pdf.

Ruby 1.8.7

Rails 2.3.14

Comment: Why would you use Rails 2.3 in 2014? I think your original error was a result of invalid credentials and then you kept solving wrong problem.

Comment: there's a couple of plugins that are heavily relied on which prevents an upgrade without a major rewrite. Do you mean the `401` error or the  `NoMethodError (undefined method 'tr' for #<StringIO:0xb5b728c4>):`. The latter is what I got immediately after fixing the `401`.

Comment: I mean 401. Did you confirm with curl that your username and pass are ok?

Comment: not confirmed with curl but username and password should be fine as I can view the file in the browser with the same credentials. I have removed those new initializer scripts and just waiting on the response from the api which can take a few minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work with the following (two new initializer scripts removed):

```
file = Tempfile.new(filename + ext) 
file.binmode
file << open(url, :http_basic_authentication => [username, password]).read
file.close
file = File.open(file.path)

return file
```

Should also mention that this is being passed to the `attachment_fu` plugin incase anyone else has problems with it.